# calling Salesforce REST API from Webpage

Tags: rest-api

How to do I call sales force REST API from external webportal.

What steps I need to do for authentication of the external URL in sales force

Answer (score 0):

By using the webservice key word you are creating something that is to be exposed through SOAP. You can select the class and use the "Generate WSDL" button to generate the WSDL that external tooling can consume.

If you want to avoid SOAP and WSDL, then make use of the @RestResource annotation instead. This also allows the content to be in JSON format which is generally easy for clients (including JavaScript apps running in the browser) to create and consume.

Note that in both cases the request will have to include some authentication information (see e.g. [OAUTH](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Digging_Deeper_into_OAuth_2.0_on_Force.com)).